# Make Sympy's solveset function return expression

Tags: python, sympy

## Question

I wanted to find a way to get `sympy`'s `solveset` function to return an expression that I can do further algebraic manipulation on. Failing this I want to convert the `solveset` output to a `sympy` expression or use an alternate function for a similar purpose.

## Minimal working example

```
# Writing an expression that I will later solve.
import sympy as sy
x, y = sy.symbols('x y')
exp1 = x + y*x + y**2
# This returns a core.syymbol.Symbol
exp2 = sy.solveset(exp1, x)
# This returns a sets.sets.FiniteSet
# Now trying to subtract a further expression results in an error.
exp2 - y
# AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute '_complement'
```